# How do I scan an array and draw my level?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making a basic game and I am now onto collision checking. I load my mapp from an array but I'm stuck on the code to draw it.

Load the array:

```
var levelArray=[
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
```

This is my code to try and draw the blocks (1's).

```
for(arrayx=0;arrayx<11;arrayx++){
        if (levelArray[arrayx][arrayy]==1){
            canvas_context.fillStyle = "blue";
            canvas_context.fillRect(arrayx*32,arrayy*32,32,32);
        }
        if (arrayx==10 && arrayy<11){
            arrayy++
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me out and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what does this have to do with collision detecting? it looks like you're just using an array to fill blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make loop inside of loop like this:

```
var x;
var y;
var lengthX;
var lengthY;

for(x = 0 , lengthX = levelArray.length ; x < lengthX ; x++){
    for(y = 0 , lengthY = levelArray[x].length ; y < lengthY ; y++){
        if(levelArray[x][y] == 1){
            //draw
        }
    }
}
```

Or the y first and x inside y loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping through each and every element of the array. use two for loops.